# Expect TCL counter within variable

Tags: tcl, expect

As an example, let's say I've defined several variables and then I call the variables made with counter variables. What would be the correct syntax for $interface$counter?

```
set interface0 $env(interface0)
set interface1 $env(interface1)
set interface2 $env(interface2)

for {set i 0} {$i < $3} {incr i 1} {
puts $interface$i
}
```

Comment: http://wiki.tcl.tk/37949

Answer (score 2):

```
set interface0 A
set interface1 B
set interface2 C

for {set i 0} {$i < 3} {incr i 1} {
    puts [set interface$i]
}
```

Dynamic variable names are always a PITA to work with. You need to get Tcl to go through 2 rounds of substitution: first to construct the variable name, second to extract the value.

Much easier to use arrays. You can get the value directly

```
array set interface {}
set interface(0) A
set interface(1) B
set interface(2) C

for {set i 0} {$i < 3} {incr i 1} {
    puts $interface($i)
}
```

Or use a dictionary

```
set interface [dict create]
dict set interface 0 A
dict set interface 1 B
dict set interface 2 C

for {set i 0} {$i < 3} {incr i 1} {
    puts [dict get $interface $i]
}
```

However, in this case, you just have monotonically increasing integer value: you want a list:

```
set interfaces [list $env(interface0) $env(interface1) $env(interface2)]

for {set i 0} {$i < $3} {incr i 1} {
    puts [lindex $interfaces $i]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It can be:

```
for {set i 0} {$i < 3} {incr i 1} {
send "This is count [set interface$i]\n"
}
```

Thank you